# How to implement SQL authentication in socket.io and separate rooms for group?

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I need to check the database the group that user is located and always send notifications to the room (cod_group) him.

**But I do not want to send sensitive data in the front-end to check in connection.**

In this case, I would use Ajax to verify in socket.io, right?

Suggests? Thanks for all!

Comment: You need to give a bit more data here. Where and how do you authenticate socket connectsions? What exactly do you want to authenticate? Maybe a bit of code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. Each user has a field in the database called "cod_group". This field allows the system to isolate the site environment. So I want to avoid the leakage of "socket broadcast". And separate for rooms

Comment: The spec is still a bit broad, but what you would do is something like this: on a new connection, authenticate the user and check the cod_group. Then put him into his group, something like module global _rooms_ array. Rooms should hold a collection of cod_group entries.  Each room is an object with connection ids as keys and all the data you need as value. So when you broadcast something, don't broadcast it to everyone, just emit to that group.